# How do you find the transfer function of a controller?

Tags: transfer-function, controller

Below is a block diagram of the system. I thought the circle symbol with the plus and minus sign was an op-amp but I'm not sure whether that's the case. I want to find the closed loop transfer function. If there was no feedback (open loop), then I think I could find the output as Y(s) = Vin*G. This would mean that the transfer function is Y(s)/Vin = G.

Any ideas for how to find the closed loop transfer function and what the circle means?

[image]

Comment: The circle is a **summation**, so in this case the output of the circle is Vin - Y(s) (note the - on the Y(s) input). Also have a look in your favourite textbook about linear systems with feedback. For sure this basic structure will be discussed there because it is the most basic negative feedback system of all. If you have no book, look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_feedback

Comment: So, do some algebra - here's a start Y(s) = G(Vi - Y(s))

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would derive the transfer function equation:

\$Y(s) = e(s)G(s)\$ where \$G(s)\$ is your gain and \$e(s)\$ is the error. The error is just what you get right after the summation block (the summing circle you have there).

Also \$e(s)=V_{in}(s)-Y(s)\$. If you now plug \$e(s)\$ into the equation for \$Y(s)\$, you get 
$$Y(s) = (V_{in}(s)-Y(s))G(s) $$
$$Y(s) = V_{in}(s)G(s)-Y(s)G(s) $$
$$Y(s)+Y(s)G(s) = V_{in}(s)G(s) $$
$$Y(s)(1+G(s)) = V_{in}(s)G(s) $$

And finally, 
$$\frac{Y(s)}{V_{in}(s)}=\frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)}  $$

As far as the summing block goes, it can physically be constructed with opamps since you can use them to create summers.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Taking the circle as as a mathematical sum, ignoring for the moment how this may be achieved in electronics.

$$ Y(s) = G(s) \cdot (V_{in} - Y(s))$$

We are asked to find the loop gain.

There are to two distinct gains here:

The open loop gain, is simply the the gain around the loop, so we assume \$ V_{in} \$ is zero, or at least constant DC, the loop gain is therefore simply \$ Y(s) \$

When we close the loop we are looking for the gain from input to output.

$$G_{cl} = \frac{Y(s)}{V_{in}}$$

$$Y(s) + Y(s) \cdot G(s) = V_{in} \cdot G(s)$$

$$G_{cl} = \frac{Y(s)}{V_{in}} = \frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)}$$

The summing function could be achieved with an op-amp but there are several other ways it could be too. In many cases the summing function and the gain \$Y(s)\$ would both be functions of the same amplifier: Regardless of whether this is a separate device or a function on the system control IC.