# How does one arrive at the following transfer function for a certain circuit?

Tags: transfer-function

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the transfer function for the following electrical system:

[image]

Where \$k\$ is some forward gain element and \$G_{s}\$ is the transfer function of some plant. According to an instruction video, the transfer function for this whole system is $$T(s) = \frac{Y}{R} = \frac{k G_{s} }{1+kG_{s}} .$$

I am wondering how this expression for \$T(s)\$ can be derived. It probably has something to do with the control mechanism, but I am not an electrical engineer so I'm not sure how to derive this expression. I do have a background in mathematics though, so maybe you can take that into account in your answer.

Comment: This is a very similar answer to what you are looking for: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/233239/108065

Comment: Visual inspection: (R-Y)*K*Gs=Y. Solve for Y/R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write out the control system into an equation and solve for Y/R ([Signal out] / [Signal in]

Sorry I have not figured out the math function yet.

Y = (R - Y)*k*Gs

Y = R*k*Gs - Y*k*Gs

Y + Y*k*Gs = R*k*Gs

Y*(1 + k*Gs) = R*k*Gs

Y/R = k*Gs / (1 + k*Gs)

Comment: Thank you! How do you see that \$ Y = (R - Y) k G_{s} \$ , though?

Comment: R is your input and Y is your output so you can start with:

Comment: Y = R

Then there us a node at which R is added and Y is subtracted. You need to think of Y and R as values at a given point. Now you have:

Y = (R - Y)

You then multiply by the gain k and the system Gs to arrive at:

Y = (R-Y)*k*Gs

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Y = Gs(R-Y)K

So, just use your algebra skills to isolate what Y is.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer function is defined as Y/R.

Walking backwards from the output to determine what Y is, you see that Y is the output of a transfer function Gs. There's an amplification of K before that so you end up with $$<stuff>*K*Gs=Y $$
"stuff" is the output of the adder/subtractor which happens to be adding R and subtracting Y so you end up with $$(R-Y)*K*Gs = Y $$

Solve for Y/R and you get the transfer function.